# Как сделать изменяющуюсю строку в c++

Tags: c++, консоль

Мне нужно каждые пол секунды водить в консоль gamestate. Я хочу что бы вместо того, что бы писать вывод на новой строке, я хочу просто менять значение gamestate в одной строке.

Comment: Ну и выводите вместо `\n` — `\r`. Если вы все время в одной строке консоли.

Comment: Спасибо, работает